# Datagrid selection checkboxes do not show

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I want to get a datagrid with checkbox to select rows. I followed the instruction here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/datagrid/selection

What am I missing?

```
<clr-datagrid [(clrDgSelected)]="selected" [clDgRowSelection]="true">
  <clr-dg-column>Name</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let item of items" [clrDgItem]="item">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{ item.name }}</clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>
</clr-datagrid>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `[clrDgRowSelection]` instead of `[clDgRowSelection]`? Seems odd that it's the only binding not to start with `clr` and I would assume it to be a typo in the documentation.

Comment: Below, @Massimo said it just got deprecated, but the documentation was not updated yet. For now, both seem to work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clDgRowSelection` is deprecated since v0.12 and is there only for backward compatibility.
Can you try with the new `clrDgRowSelection` ?

BTW, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datagrid-selection) you can find an working example also with the old one.
could you post a full example??

Comment: Thanks for the working example. It showed me that I forgot to initialize the selected variable as an array!

Comment: Is there a way to show and hide the selection column?

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way, I updated the stackblitz demo to set `selected` to undefined to hide checkboxes. But in this case I think you remove the whole selection feature

Comment: Not sure either, but working good for me. :-) Thanks @Massimo

Comment: Only one thing that I saw is the number at the button sometimes increase and get more than the quantity of element in the table. I think it happens when the table is refreshed behind the scene. Will need some tweacking...

Comment: link has been removed :(

Comment: yep sorry I removed by mistake, in general was showing to use the new attribute instead of the deprecated one